# Topological Sort in DNS

Tags: dns, topological-sort

**Is there any application of Topological Sort in Domain Name Server?**

I am thinking if there is any use of it, in Web Servers to resolve Server Redirection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Topological Sorting is mainly used for scheduling jobs from the given dependencies among jobs. In computer science, applications of this type arise in instruction scheduling, ordering of formula cell evaluation when recomputing formula values in spreadsheets, logic synthesis, determining the order of compilation tasks to perform in makefiles, data serialization, and resolving symbol dependencies in linkers

Answer (score 0):

If you can expand on what you're actually trying to achieve, we can probably give you a better answer. With regular BIND, there are some methods you can use to give out different answers for the same request (views, forwarders, etc). However, there's no real ability to "sort" by topology as topology in this case is just an idea. Geographically (topology) preferential answers is usually  something you will find in global load balancers.

Comment: Yeah,
I was actually intended to ask the use of it, in Load Balancing of Web Servers.